# Is a ~2/3rds-stop delta between Olympus and Panasonic metering typical?

Tags: olympus, metering, panasonic-lumix

Moving from Olympus (OM-1) to Panasonic (S5-II), I'm finding that comparing the whole-scene metering modes (ESP on the OM-1, "multi-metering" on the Panasonic), the Panasonic tends to underexpose compared to what I'm used to.

To avoid leaving unused headroom, it looks like on the Panasonic I'd want to set exposure compensation +2/3rds of a stop.

Is this typical/expected/reasonable, or does it imply that I have my settings off somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those metering modes are not equivalent... ESP is more akin to smart center weighted metering as opposed to overall average/multi metering.

So yes, they are quite likely to result in different (recommended) exposures depending on the scene/situation.